# Dependency injection in .Net without virtual method calls?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, clr

I've been thinking about whether it's possible to apply the DI pattern without incurring the cost of virtual method calls (which according to experiments I did can be up to 4 times slower than non-virtual calls). The first idea I had was to do dependency injection via generics:

```
sealed class ComponentA<TComponentB, TComponentC> : IComponentA 
    where TComponentB : IComponentB
    where TComponentC : IComponentC
{ ... }
```

Unfortunately the CLR still does method calls via the interfaces even when concrete implementations of TComponentB and TComponentC are specified as generic type parameters and all of the classes are declared as sealed. The only way to get the CLR to do non-virtual calls is by changing all of the classes to structs (which implement the interfaces). Using struct doesn't really make sense for DI though and makes the issue below even more unsolvable.

The second issue with the above solution is that it can't handle circular references. I can't think of any way, either by C# code, or by constructing expression trees, to handle circular references because that would entail infinitely recursing generic types. (.Net does support generic types referencing itself, but it doesn't seem to generalize to this case.) Since only structs can cause the CLR to bypass the interfaces, I don't think this problem is solvable at all because circular references between structs could cause a paradox.

There's only one other solution I can think of and it's guaranteed to work - emit all of the classes from scratch at runtime, maybe basing them on compiled classes as templates. Not really an ideal solution though.

Anyone have better ideas?

Edit: In regards to most of the comments, I guess I should say that this is filed under "pure intellectual curiosity" I debated whether to ask this because I do realize that I don't have any concrete case in which it's necessary. I was just thinking about it for fun and was wondering whether anyone else came across this before.

Comment: 4 times slower?? I find that hard to believe. I'd file this under "Premature Optimization"...

Comment: This is for a personal, no-deadlines project, so I get to indulge in premature optimization :)

Comment: @jthg - Premature optimization can hurt more than just deadlines.

Comment: That looks a lot like policy templates in C++.

Comment: @jthg - I can't speak for Andrew, but maintainability, clarity, readability, and testability generally provide more bang for the buck than optimization.

Comment: @jthg - I mean that premature optimization can cause you to make decisions about the structure and design of your code that can make it difficult to maintain and scale (among other things).

Comment: @BFree - Yeah, it's 4 times slower if the method is a simple one-liner.

Comment: But what are we talking about? 4*2ms=8ms? And how accurate are your timings? Presumably you're using a load of iterations?

Comment: Just a rudimentary test of timing a loop that calls the method 4 billion times (with the 4000000000 number being user input in case the compiler/CLR pulls tricks like C++ compilers). The loop that calls via an interface is 4 times slower than the loop that calls directly.

Comment: Alright, but in absolute time per call, no one is gonna notice a difference. Unless your use case is to call the method hundreds of thousands of times in a loop. You're worrying about nothing. Seriously, if we all fell into that premature optimisation trap, we would ship jack sh1t.

Answer (score 4):

Typical example of trying to completely over-engineer something in my opinion. Just *don't compromise* your design because you can save a few 10's of milliseconds - if it is even that.

Are you seriously suggesting that because of the `callvirt` instructions, your app ends up being so significantly slower that users (those people you write the app for) will notice any difference - *at* all? I doubt that very much.

Answer (score 3):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt.aspx) explains why you can't optimize the virtual call.

Answer (score 2):

While a `callvirt` instruction does take longer this is usually done because it provides a cheap `null` check for the CLR prior to making the call to the method.  A `callvirt` shouldn't take significantly longer than a `call` instruction especially considering the `null` check.

Have you found that you could significantly improve the performance of your application by creating types (either `structs` or classes with static methods) that allow you to guarantee that the C# compiler will emit `call` instructions rather than `callvirt` instructions?

The reason I ask is that I am wondering if you are going to create an unmaintainable code base that is brittle and hard to use simply to solve a problem that may or may not exist.

Comment: Yeah, using structs does reduce the overhead to almost nothing. I guess I might have mis-interpreted the cause of the improvement.

Comment: Using structs also reduce memory pressure but they are limited in their ability to elegantly model a problem domain.